# Get page title from Zend's headTitle()

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I'm setting the page title using:

```
$title = 'Sign In';
$this->headTitle($title);
```

And in the layout.phtml, this is used to generate the title element in the header:

```
echo $this->headTitle('SalesCom')->setSeparator(' - ')->setAutoEscape(false);
```

How would I then be able to get just the $title from within the layout.phtml to set a page title within the body itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HeadTitle helper actually implements ArrayAccess, so you can simply do something like this:

```
$title = $this->headTitle();
$part  = $title[0];
```

If you have PHP 5.4, it's even better:

```
$part = $this->headTitle()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple 'segments', you can retrieve the whole title this way:

```
<?php echo $this->headTitle()->renderTitle() ?>
```

Source: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-title.html